# How to avoid closure when you need to provide callback to install event handlers

Tags: javascript, closures

I have an object `Map3` that handles displaying of the markers of my dataset on google maps. It is a generic object, I want to use it in many different applications, so I defined a callback called `markerInstall` that will install custom event handlers to my markers. Example usage (simplified):

```
var map = new Map3({
    markerInstall: function (marker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
            window.open('detail.php?id=' + this.my.id);
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) {
            // do something else
        }
    }
});
```

The Map3 object contains loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ...
    var m = new google.maps.Marker(opts);
    this.markerInstall(m);
    ...
}
```

Now, since `markerInstall` is called for each marker separately (I have hundreds of them), this will create a closure for each marker, and the closure will not be released until the end of the application (because it is refered by the event handler). I consider this a problem, since it will consume some memory. **How can I avoid the closure and keep the object generic enough?** Or shouldn't I bother too much, because it won't be so much of memory consumed?

Comment: To downvoter - please add a comment how is my question unclear or not useful.

Comment: I don't think you've got anything to worry about. The only thing in the closure is the "marker" parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more the number of different functions that matters than that each function is getting it's own closure. You can move the "generated ones" out of the function generating them and use a reference instead

```
var map = (function () { // closure here to protect namespace from `listeners`
    var listeners = {
            'click': function(e) {
                    window.open('detail.php?id=' + this.my.id);
                },
            'mouseover': function (e) {}
        };
    return new Map3({
        markerInstall: function (marker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', listeners['click']);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', listeners['mouseover']);
        }
    });
}());
```

This will only work because you're not actually using any data to generate the handlers so they're all exactly the same already.

Comment: No reason to write `listeners['click']` - `listeners.click` works just fine.

Comment: I don't get your comment *"This will only work because you're not actually using any data to generate them so they're all exactly the same."* How can you now that? Did you see the `...` in my code? I didn't provide all of my code since it is not important for the question. Of course I use the `data[i]` to generate markers.

Comment: @Tomas You didn't `var` anything at the `markerInstall` level, any above will still be shared and any inside the handlers would be the same, `this` changes on the context and `e.target` on the _Event_.

Comment: @Pointy True, but as I'm using it as a dictionary I prefer bracket notation. I mean, it'll be standard even if you have some crazy custom events with hyphens etc. going on. (I was also too lazy to write it as a loop)

Comment: Ok sorry Paul I misunderstood you. Maybe you should replace *"them"* with *"handlers"* in your last sentence. I thought you meant markers instead. +1 This is cool solution!